# app not found 4oh4.php

Tags: facebook

I created a verified developer account and i developed 2 applications. Both of them are for creating tabs in facebook pages. i created them and i installed them in 2 different sample facebook pages. now i want to install them to my clients facebook pages and i cannot find the applications. when i am logged in as the developer i can see the apps in the search results but when i try to open the app page it gives me a 4oh4.php page. when i am logged in as another user i cannot see the app in the results at all.

Answer (score 0):

Are your apps running in sandbox mode? You can check this at Settings > Advanced

Comment: until now when i wanted to access my app and add it to a page i searched it in the facebook search bar. not it appears but when i click it gives me a 404.php page. so in order to add it now i go to the developers page and then in edit app and on the left side there is a link "view app profile page" and then you can add it. in case someone else is having the same problem. for some reason facebook decided to give a 404.php page when you try to access it through search.

Answer (score 0):

Login in application admin account and open bellow url :--

https://developers.facebook.com/

Step 1:- click on 'APPS' drop-down menu and choose your application from lists.

Step2:- Click on 'SETTING' TAB (Left Side) and enter your data in "App Domains" and "Contact Email" fields. Submit the form.

Step3:- Click on "STATUS AND REVIEW" tab and click "YES" for following option **"Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"** then it will available publicly.

Setp4:- After launch please check all url (js,css,images) should secure(HTTPS) otherwise browser will block content